# How do I split components into smaller files while using Vuejs from CDN and running Codekit?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, cdn

I should preface this that this is not a serious app, but instead a framework for quick prototyping so performance or compatibility isn't an issue.

I'm currently running Codekit to get my Scss and Build folder. And I've included VueJS from a CDN in the header. I also have a components.js file which contains the following:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({});

app.component("list-heading", {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    extra: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  template: `

<div class="list-heading">
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
    <div v-if="extra">{{extra}}</div>
</div>

`,
});

app.mount("#app");
```

And this works exactly how I want it. Except, I'd like to just for the sake of being organised split up each component in small files and import them, but can't manage to sort it out. Like this:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({});

import './list-heading.js';

app.mount("#app");
```

I know the last code isn't functional, it's just for illustration purposes. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**list-heading.js:**

```js
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    extra: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  template: `
<div class="list-heading">
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
    <div v-if="extra">{{extra}}</div>
</div>
`
}
```

**app.js:**

```js
import ListHeading from './list-heading.js';

const app = Vue.createApp({});
app.component("list-heading", ListHeading);

app.mount("#app");
```

---

...or:

**list-heading.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
  //props, template, etc...
})
```

**app.js:**

```
import ListHeading from './list-heading.js';

const app = Vue.createApp({
  components: { ListHeading }
});

app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: Wow! You're amazing!!! That totally worked, but I got a warning and corrected it by setting type="module" on the javascript include. But somehow, that breaks my other javascripts.I have included the components in the footer, and below that all the scripts that i need to have in the footer. Normal javascript.

Comment: You don't have to do everything into one `<script>` tag. But the one instantiating your Vue app should have `type="module"`, indeed. And it should come last, after you loaded everything else (i.e.: Vue from cdn, any other dependencies). If you have trouble separating into `<script>` tags, repro what you have on codesanbdobx.io and I'll patch it.

Comment: I managed to solve it accidentaly, on the footer-scripts.js i added type="application/javascript" and defer, and now it works. So... in conclusion: You rule and just made my night! :)